# Backup and Migrate gives me a tar ball

Tags: 7, migrations, backups

I have a local site and a development site. I want to replace my development site with my local site. I used the [Backup and Migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module to backup the development site into a `.gz` file. All good. But when I did the same again with the local environment, it came back as a `.tar` file, no matter which compression option I chose.

When I tried to restore onto the development site using the local site's tarball, it specified it needs a `.gz` or `.zip` file. So I ran:

> tar -cvzf 127.0.1.1-2015-01-12T17-23-50.sitearchive.tar.gz
>   127.0.1.1-2015-01-12T17-23-50.sitearchive.tar

This time, it came back with this error:

> Unable to restore from file
>   /tmp/backup_migrate_vbDBRs.0.1.1-2015-01-12t17-23-50.sitearchive.tar
>   because a tar file can't be restored to this database.

How can I correctly restore a backup from my local site onto the development site. Or is this method completely wrong and I should be doing something else, like creating a new site from scratch and restoring that?

Comment: A tat file is just a "packed" file containing one or more files, which are not compressed (gzip are). Looks like an issue on the module. Try compressing the tar file into gzip.

Comment: @AyeshK, thanks for your idea, but I did what you suggested already with `tar -cvzf` which turns it into a `.tar.gz` file, and it came back with the 'Unable to restore...' error. Any more ideas?

Comment: I'm afraid that the problem isn't with the suffix. I used the Backup & Migrate module to download the db (also full site) in various formats, including zip. It won't accept any of these styles -- and it failed even when I copied the various files to the server's backup folder (so I used the option "Restore from saved backups" rather than "from uploaded file").

Comment: Have you tried using phpmyadmin export and import?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with the module.

The most likely cause of the problem is that your local system is missing [gzip](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_gzip.htm), so the backup and migrate module is unable to turn the tar-file into a gzipped tar file.

The command to do that is not `tar -cvzf` (which you've tried), but `gzip`. I.e.:

```
gzip 127.0.1.1-2015-01-12T17-23-50.sitearchive.tar
```

This should produce a valid `127.0.1.1-2015-01-12T17-23-50.sitearchive.tar.gz`, but if you try this on the local system, it will probably fail telling you that it can't locate *gzip*.

The best fix would be to install *gzip* on the local system.

Alternatively, you may export the file to some system that has *gzip*, and do the gizipping there.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I will test this out when I'm back at work!